# Excel Error Handling - Lookup and Return Employee ID

Tags: excel, if-statement, error-handling, vlookup, nested-if

**Request:**

Please assist w\ formula logic to provide error handling and Vlookup functionality across two possible columns (within table array) and return employee ID (third column in array).

**Goal:**

Create an auto-populating attendance tracker that looks up the inputted phone number and returns their employee ID on an embedded "Roster" worksheet. Also, I am trying to give functionality for vlooking up across two phone numbers.

**"Attendance Tracker" worksheet Table Layout:** (emphasis in italics)

DATE | TIME | *CALLER ID* | TYPE | REASON | DETAILS | *EMPLOYEE #* | ETC...

- Caller ID = Column D
- Employee # = Column I

**"Roster" worksheet table-array for VLOOKUP**

- Column H = "Contact Primary"
- Column I = "Contact Secondary"
- Column J = "Employee Number"

**Primary Formula(s)**

- "**First**"=VLOOKUP(D2,Roster!H:J,3,0) <--- Looks up emp number against "Contact Primary"
- "**Second**"=VLOOKUP(D2,Roster!H:J,2,0) <--- Looks up emp number against "Contact Secondary"

**My Attempt**
=IF(D2="","",IF(ISERROR(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(First)),VLOOKUP(Second),VLOOKUP(First))),"Add # to Roster",VLOOKUP(FIRST))))

**MY RESULTS**
"Caller ID" left blank - Perfect! Top level if-statement fixes blanks.
"Caller ID" exists in "Contact Primary" Column - Perfect! Value Returns.
"Caller ID" exists in "Contact Secondary" Column - Oh No! "Add # to Roster" returns.
"Caller ID" DOES NOT exist in either "Contact Primary/Secondary" - Oh No! "Add # to Roster" returns.

I hope I explained that well enough. And thank you so much in advance if you are able to assist!

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Excel 2007 introduced the [IFERROR() function](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/IFERROR-function-f59bacdc-78bd-4924-91df-a869d0b08cd5?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) which greatly reduces the size of error controlled `VLOOKUP()` formulas.

Comment: Jeeped - Developing on Excel 2010, but our company still has some systems rocking out Excel 2003. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you want may be:

```
=IF(D2="","",IF(AND(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,Roster!H:J,3,0)),ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,Roster!I:J,2,0))),"Add # to Roster", IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,Roster!H:J,3,0)),(VLOOKUP(D2,Roster!I:J,2,0)),(VLOOKUP(D2,Roster!H:J,3,0)))))
```

Comment: I appreciate it! Look forward to testing tomorrow, I'll update this answer then.